# Recess Framework v0.2: Json Request does not insert values

Tags: php, json, post, frameworks, recess

I am facing trouble while posting JSON DATA to recess framework. The JSON data posted perfect from the browser end. But when i get that from the server end it becomes null. I don't know the reason.

SMPLE EXT JS CODE:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url : 'http://localhost:8888/index.php' ,
method: 'POST',
jsonData: { dining: {name: 'test',},},
success: function ( result, request ) {
  alert(result.responseText);
},
});
```

I can get the JSON data when i am using CORE PHP. But the issue was when im with RECESS FRAMEWORK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer after deep googling. Thanks to **Hirnhamster** the user, http://forums.recessframework.org/.

**Solution**

The solution is - in contrast to finding the real problem - rather easy:

**1. Step:**

Open the file DefaultPolicy.class.php in recess/recess/framework.
Go to method preprocess(..).
Add the line $this->reparameterizeForFormat($request); as last command before returning.
The function should now look like this:

```
<?php
    public function preprocess(Request &$request) {
        $this->getHttpMethodFromPost($request);

        $this->forceFormatFromResourceString($request);

        $this->reparameterizeForFormat($request);

        return $request;
    }
?>
```

**2. Step**

In the same file, go to method forceFormatFromResourceString(...).
Change the line $format = substr($lastPart, $lastDotPosition + 1); to $format = strtolower(substr($lastPart, $lastDotPosition + 1));
Add the line $request->format = $format; below if($format !== '') {
The function should now look like this:

```
<?php
    protected function forceFormatFromResourceString(Request &$request) {

        $lastPartIndex = count($request->resourceParts) - 1;
        if($lastPartIndex < 0) return $request;

        $lastPart = $request->resourceParts[$lastPartIndex];

        $lastDotPosition = strrpos($lastPart, Library::dotSeparator);
        if($lastDotPosition !== false) {
            $format = strtolower(substr($lastPart, $lastDotPosition + 1));
            if($format !== '') {
                $request->format = $format;
                $mime = MimeTypes::preferredMimeTypeFor($format);
                if($mime !== false) {
                    $request->accepts->forceFormat($format);
                    $request->setResource(substr($request->resource, 0, strrpos($request->resource, Library::dotSeparator)));
                }
            }
        }

        return $request;
    }
?>
```

**3. Step**

In the same file, go to method reparameterizeForFormat(...).
(Be astonished that this function already exists :P).
Change Format::JSON to "json" and Format::XML to "xml"
The function should now look like this:

```
<?php
    protected function reparameterizeForFormat(Request &$request) {

        if($request->format == "json") {
            $method = strtolower($request->method);
            $request->$method = json_decode($request->input, true);
        } else if ($request->format == "xml") {
            // TODO: XML reparameterization in request transformer
        }
        return $request;
    }
?>
```

**4. Step**

You are done.

**For Detailed Solution**:

[http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://forums.recessframework.org/topic/189-json-request-doesnt-insert-values-in-v02/](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://forums.recessframework.org/topic/189-json-request-doesnt-insert-values-in-v02/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'http://localhost:8888/index.php' ,
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: { dining: {name: 'test'} },
    success: function( result, request ) {
        alert(result.responseText);
    }
});
```

You're writing Javascript. Some "commas" after } aren't valid.

Comment: Hey rijuk, Thanks for your suggestion. But the changes too cause the same issue.

Comment: For Solution: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://forums.recessframework.org/topic/189-json-request-doesnt-insert-values-in-v02/